# Table inside table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a database that stores values from 5 different sensors, all sorted in dates and times.

So far I've created one table "sensors (sens1,sens2,sens3,sens4,sesn5)" in which I store 100's of continuous readings.

Now my question is how I would sort these readings in dates.
Say, one session starts, fills out the sensors table with 40 values for each sensor. How would I store this session in another table, and how would I automate creations of these sessions?

Essential and dream situation:

[image]

Comment: Where is the date in the database? There is nothing like "table in table" in any database I'm familiar with. More details will be needed to answer the question.

Comment: What exactly is a session? You could have just one table with id | sensor id | timestamp | value.

Answer (score 4):

You should have a table that has sensor readings.  The more general structure is to have one row per sensor per value, with columns like:

- SensorId
- ReadingDateTime
- Value

If all five sensors are read at the same time (like, for instance, for a weather station that records temperature, air pressure, humidity, wind speed, and wind direction all at once), then you can have one row per reading,with five columns, one for each value.

As for creating "sessions".  Either that is in the data or you should do the work after gathering the data.

Comment: But the I have to store atleast 50 readings/min. Seems retrieveing these afterwards is gonna be one heck of a search, no?

Comment: So, the readings for all five sensors are stored simultaneously, then?

Comment: @Rasmus Hjorth Lüdeking - if you had only 4 sensors, or 6, would you expect to have to re-structure your entire database? This solution wouldn't need any structural changes if the number of sensors changed. You should add indices to suit the retrievals you expect to be running.

Comment: I expect 50+ simultaneously readings/min. I need to be able to extract a given session or "set" of these by the date they are registered.

Comment: 50 readings/min is less than one per second.  That is not much.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Table which is called "tSession" for example.
This table has the Parameters "idSession" (integer) and "StartSessionDate" (date time)

in your table "Sensors" you add the column "FK_Session" now if you start your session you create an entry in "tSession" and then you add your Sensor Data.

With the Function Last_Inserted_ID you get the inserted "idSession". Insert this value into "FK_Session"